# TensorFlow multi-label accuracy metrics

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am currently using a TensorFlow for multi-label classification problems (9 labels in total) and this is the model compile line:

```
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

***y_true*** label of my model consists of 2 of 1's and 7 of 0's (e.g., [0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0]).

I tried several models using TensorFlow, but no matter how complicated the model was, the accuracy has been very poor, with accuracy around 0.3.

I was wondering whether the Keras accuracy metrics works also in the case of multi-label classifications. For example, if ***y_pred*** has a probability value of [0.1, 0.9, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1], does Keras pick out the top 2 probability from ***y_pred***, convert them into binary labels of [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0] and then compare the accuracy with the ones with ***y_true*** labels?

If not, do I have to implement my own metrics function?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't use Keras, but I would think the coding of the predicted is such that if the individual label probability exceeds 0.5, then it's coded a 1, zero otherwise.   For example, if multivariate linear regression is used, you can trick the code into a truth label of y=(-1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1) and then any positive predicted is coded a 1 and negative predicted coded a zero, such as y=(-0.3,0.6,-0.4,-0.2,-0.3,0.4,-0.2,-0.5,-0.4).  Point is, zero is the threshold.  In your case, 0.5 is probably the threshold.

Comment: Another point is for a binary string of length 9, there are 2^9=512 potential combinations of ones and zeroes.  Thus you would need to ensure wide coverage of the outcome space (class labels) to train your model.  The poor performance is probably due to the data and the selected model.  Maybe try using MSE for error instead of cross-entropy.   MSE would be equal to 0.5 * [(0-0.1)^2 + (1-0.9)^2 + ... + (0-0.1)^2]. I rarely use cross-entropy for ANNs, and rather often use MSE for classification and function approximation.

Comment: Maybe you should try to change the loss function to 'categorical_crossentropy' since you have a multi class problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, accuracy shows what portion of predicted labels match original labels.

As stated in the [official documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/Accuracy):

> This metric creates two local variables, total and count, that are used to compute the frequency with which y_pred **matches** y_true. This frequency is ultimately returned as binary accuracy: an idempotent operation that simply divides total by count.

This metric shows the portion of probability predictions **equal** to true labels.

The  [tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/BinaryAccuracy) rounds the predicted probabilities by a given threshold (0.5 by default). So, if the model output is [0.9, 0.3, 0.6], it will be rounded to [1, 0, 1] before comparing to the true labels.

However, the accuracy metric will show not only where the predicted 1's match true labels, but where 0's match 0's. In most cases its bad for multi-label problems, as there is imbalance between 1's and 0's in the data. In your case, you have 3,5 times more 0's than 1's. If the model of yours will output only zeros, it will indeed be a bad model, but as 7/9 of original labels are zeros too, it will have 7/9 or almost 78 % accuracy right off the bat.

I suggest to use other metrics for multi-label classification:

1. **Precision**, which shows what portion of predicted 1's are actually 1's
2. **Recall**, which shows what portion of actual 1's are "found" and predicted as 1's
3. **F1 and F-beta**, which sum up precision and recall

Individually, those metrics will not give you much information on the performance of the model, so it's better to use them combined. You can read more about them in [sklearn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_fscore_support.html) and [in this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/performance-metrics-confusion-matrix-precision-recall-and-f1-score-a8fe076a2262).

As of implementations, there are official implementations of [Precision](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/Precision) and [Recall](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/Recall) in Tensorflow, and Tensorflow Addons has [F1Score](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/metrics/F1Score) and [FBetaScore](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/metrics/F1Score).

Comment: Official implementations of Precision and Recall in Tensorflow does not support multi-label classification!